# Power Automate - Flow adding duplicate entries

Tags: power-automate

I have 2 SharePoint sites (SiteA and SiteB) In siteA I have an excel file called LocationA, when this file is edited (rows added, rows edited or rows deleted) I want to reflect these changes in another excel file called LocationB which is stored in SiteB (I have not added the delete operation yet but suggestions on how I might do so are welcomed).

The issue is that the flow is adding rows instead of updating the existing rows in LocationB.

Please find my flow below (it is running without errors but the output is the problem)

[image]

[image]

**Note**

The expression in the filter array is **string(items('Apply_to_each')?['ID'])** which changes the ID field to String

The expression in condition 2 is **empty(body('Filter_array'))** this condition checks if the list item exists in excel

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the action to add a row in the power automate, you need to change the action for example, Update a row. That will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).